Передача данных в каллбеке inline кнопки telebot
Всем привет, возник вопрос, как передавать данные вместе с callback запросом при нажатии inline кнопки, и передавать не в callback.data, типа как в get запросе, только в каллбеке telebot. Прошу помогите, предлагайте любое решение

а чем вас callback.data не устраивает? вы бы описали что именно хотите добиться, чтобы было понимание что вам советовать
